# c# Converting UTC time to Central including timezone in DateTime object

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone, utc

I'm converting the UTC time, taken from my local Server time to Central standard time. I have this running on a server in Germany.

Converting the time and date works, but when a library i have converts it to a string it has a wrong Timezone offset.

It comes out as **2019-05-11T14:44:09+02:00**
when i need it to be **2019-05-11T14:44:09-06:00**

```
TimeZoneInfo CRtimezone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Standard Time");
TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.UtcNow, CRtimezone);
```

The **+02:00** is the UTCoffset for Germany, which i don't want, even the the time and date are correctly in Central Time.

Is there a way to pass or include the offset in the DateTime object?

Comment: `[ConvertedDateTime].ToString($"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt{crTimeZone.BaseUtcOffset}" );`

Comment: Thanks, but i need to pass a DateTime object to the library

Comment: `DateTime` doesn't carry `TimeZone` informations. `zzzz` will be the local offset + DST.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to pass or include the offset in the DateTime object?

No, `DateTime` structure does *not* have [UTC Offset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) but [`DateTimeOffset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset?view=netframework-4.8) has. If you *really* wanna keep your UTC Offset value in your code, I suggest you to work with `DateTimeOffset` instead of `DateTime`.

Since it doesn't keep UTC Offset value, when you get it's *textual* (aka string) representation, you *still* get the offset value of your server in Germany (includes `K`, `z`, `zz` and `zzz` specifiers by the way). `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc` method returns a `DateTime` instance, the offset value you might wanna represent depends on *how* you want to show it.

One option might be that you might wanna concatenate [The Sortable ("s") Format Specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#the-sortable-s-format-specifier) representation of your DateTime and your [`TimeZoneInfo.BaseUtcOffset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.baseutcoffset?view=netframework-4.8) value.

```
TimeZoneInfo CRtimezone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Standard Time");
$"{TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.UtcNow, CRtimezone).ToString("s")}{CRtimezone.BaseUtcOffset}".Dump();
```